# How to make the Wordpress Editor not accept HTML?

Tags: php, editor, wp-editor

So basically, I am using the Wordpress editor on my site and I do not want my users posting ANY HTML in it at all since it can cause some problems.

My Wordpress Editor is currently like this:

```
<?php wp_editor( get_the_content() , 'post_content'); ?>
```

In simple terms, I would basically like it to just look like a simple HTML `textarea`, and strip all HTML tags (like what the PHP function `strip_tags` does. Although, I cannot get this PHP functionality working with a simple `textarea`... Not to sure why, just a coding problem with my theme.

So yes, is something like this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Remove post type support for the editor:

```
add_action(
  'init',
  function() {
    remove_post_type_support( 'post', 'editor');
  }
);
```

Now add a new meta box containing only a `textarea`

```
// print a new meta box
function generic_cb($post) {
  $content = (!empty($post->post_content)) ? $post->post_content : '';
  echo '<textarea name="content">'.$content.'</textarea>';
}

function add_before_editor($post) {
  global $post;
  add_meta_box(
    'generic_box', // id, used as the html id att
    __( 'Text Only Content' ), // meta box title
    'generic_cb', // callback function, spits out the content
    'post', // post type or page. This adds to posts only
    'pre_editor', // context, where on the screen
    'high' // priority, where should this go in the context
  );
  do_meta_boxes('post', 'pre_editor', $post);
}
add_action('edit_form_after_title','add_before_editor');
```

And save

```
// strip your data on save
function strip_post_content_markup($data) {
  if (!empty($data['post_content'])) {
    $data['post_content'] = strip_tags($data['post_content']);
  }
  return $data;
}
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data','strip_post_content_markup',1);
```

That is the cleanest solution I can come up with.

Comment: Seems like a great solution, but I am extremely confused on how to get this working. Could you break it down a little for me by any chance? Am I basically removing my piece of code that I posted with all of your code?

Comment: If you paste those blocks of code into a plugin or MU-PLugin file, even your themes's `functions.php`, it should work. I left formatting the textarea up to you.